# Laravel 5 belongsTo(classname::class) doesn't works

Tags: php, laravel-5

Due to a Model Name change, my class `Student` doesn't works properly now.
With a database called `assos`:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`student_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

linked with a model `Asso`,

The query `App\Asso::first()->belongsTo(Student::class)` returns `null`

When the query `App\Asso::first()->belongsTo('App\Student','student_id')` returns the associated student.

I don't understand why `belongsTo(Student::class)` doesn't work properly. Can you help me to figure it out?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Eloquent: Relationships One To One](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) :

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name
>   of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.

Since you seem to be defining a relationship inline, the method name likely isn't `student` so it's not looking for `student_id`, it's looking for `mehtodname_id`.

In your second example you're telling it which field to look for the relation in, so it's looking at the right one.

Unrelated to the question specifically, but you're really misusing relationship methods. These should be defined in the model.

Comment: Don't worry about the relationship use. It was only for illustrating this post :) Thanks a lot!